# RelativeLayout set custom View y

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am having a little trouble with this relative layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/one_string" 
        android:onClick="goToScene2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/two_string" 
        android:onClick="goToScene1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/three_string" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/custView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:url="@drawable/panel_sets" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

wich renders the activity like this (scene2 in transition):
[image]

But i want to move ImageView like this image in order to later move it by aplying a transition in other layout.xml (this will be scene1). How can i do it?
[image]

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Use Custom SlidingDrawer and canvas object to draw whatever you want
1.Create Custom class by implementing View and try this:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);            canvas.drawPaint(paint);paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);            canvas.drawCircle(100,100,30,paint);
```

In XML Layout try to set yout custom class and slidingdrawer

```
<SlidingDrawer 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/Mydrawer" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:handle="@+id/handle"
android:content="@+id/content"><com.exmaple.MyCustomView
android:id="@+id/customview" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"></com.exmaple.MyCustomView><ImageView 
android:id="@id/handle" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/def_tray" /></SlidingDrawer>
```

And finally in you Activity defined what happen when drawer close and open

```
    MyslidingDrawer.setOnDrawerCloseListener(new OnDrawerCloseListener() {                @Overridepublic void onDrawerClosed(){}});MyCustomView customView = (MyCustomView) findViewById(R.id.mycontent);customView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {@Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {return true;}});
```